# php session variables getting lost in next page

Tags: php, html, variables, session

I am right now tired with this problem and I feel like leaving web programming. I have created a form and I have named the file '***index.php***'. The code is here:

```
   <form action='login.php' method='post'><br>
<center><input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:320px;' placeholder='Username' required name='username'><br></center>
<center><input type='password' class='form-control' style='width:320px;' placeholder='Password' required name='password'><br></center><br>

<center><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' name='login'>Log In</button></center>
</form><br><br>
```

Upon clicking submit, the process takes place at '***login.php***' and I am inserting the code. Here I have constructed a session variable which works fine in this page only. The code is here:

```
 <?php
session_start();
ob_start();


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "plusyou";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// variables
$UName = $_POST["username"];
$Password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT FName, UName, Password, Email FROM users WHERE UName='$UName' AND Password='$Password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //variables
        $_session["Email"] = $row["Email"];
        echo $_session["Email"];

        echo "<a href='home.php'>Home</a>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}




ob_end_flush();

?>
```

In the home page, the session variable does not work. Please let me know any of my mistakes here. Any sort of help will be appreciated. The code for the '***home.php***' file is here:

```
   <?php
session_start();

echo $_session["Email"];

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$_SESSION` variable always needs to be uppercase, as it is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: No, because it is a superglobal. What you are doing is essentially creating a new variable called `$_session` whilst the superglobal is and will always be `$_SESSION`

Comment: @KowsarRahmanSadit If it helped, then please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` needs to be capitalised.

Also, please hash+salt your passwords:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: The OP also needs to use prepared statements as their code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using $_session small case.

Please try $_SESSION with uppercase. Replace all $_session with $_SESSION and try again.

May be this will help.